# Python - Passing values from one Dataframe to another query

Tags: pandas, amazon-redshift

I am trying to perform a SQL query in Python where in I am trying to pass output of a Dataframe as part of the where clause.

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
con = psycopg2.connect (db1_details)
con1 = psycopg2.connect (db2_details)
```

This has all the bills generated

```
data = pd.read_sql("""select bill_id from sales where date > '2019-01-01'""", con = con)
```

Now I am trying to pull all customers that created bill after `2019-01-01` as obtained in the above query and is stored in `data`

```
customer_details = f"""select cust_name, bill_id from customers where bill_id in {data}"""
```

I am not sure how to pass in value from dataframe to another query as part of the loop.

Edit:

View of `data.head()`

```
bill_id
1001
1002
1003
1006
1007
```

Comment: kindly show the data dataframe structure

Comment: show data.head()

Comment: @tawab_shakeel, have updated the post with a view the head for the Dataframe. It just has one column with the `bill_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column name is `bill_id` and need loop per each unique customer:

```
for cust in data['bill_id'].unique():
    customer_details = f"""select cust_name, bill_id from customers where bill_id in ({cust})"""
    print (customer_details)
    select cust_name, bill_id from customers where bill_id in (1001)
    select cust_name, bill_id from customers where bill_id in (1002)
    select cust_name, bill_id from customers where bill_id in (1003)
    select cust_name, bill_id from customers where bill_id in (1006)
    select cust_name, bill_id from customers where bill_id in (1007)

    data = pd.read_sql(customer_details, con=con1)
```

Or if need all unique customers:

```
all_data = ', '.join(data['bill_id'].unique().astype(str))
customer_details = f"""select cust_name, bill_id from customers where bill_id in ({all_data})"""
print (customer_details)
select cust_name, bill_id from customers where bill_id in (1001, 1002, 1003, 1006, 1007)

data = pd.read_sql(customer_details, con=con1)
```

Comment: thanks for this. Could you please help me on how could I pass `query` to query into `con1`

Comment: @jezrael you should fetch unique bill_ids from data in your both solutions

Comment: @tawab_shakeel - it is same like first solution, if one value there is no `(1001, )` but `(1001)`

Comment: @jezrael you are right i have check this your answer is right

Answer (score 1):

1. Fetch unique bill_ids from data
2. convert those list into tuple and send this into query

```
unique_bill_id = list(data["bill_id"].unique())
if len(unique_bill_id ) == 1:
     unique_bill_id.append(unique_key[0])

query = "select cust_name, bill_id from customers where bill_id in {};".format(tuple(unique_bill_id))
df = pd.read_sql_query(query,con=con1)
```

Comment: thanks for this. Could you please help me on how could I pass `query` to query into `con1`

Comment: no problem @scottmartin upvote or approve those answer you found helpful so that more people can benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

You could join the 2 tables like this

```
select distinct c.cust_name, c.bill_id 
from customers as c
join sales as s on c.bill_id=s.bill_id and s.date > '2019-01-01'
```

That could be more efficient.